# French Bulldog very itchy

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition, allergies

My French bulldog has always been “itchy” and has taken medication to help, but it’s never really gone away or help take the edge off. Today, it looks to have flared up even more.

Does anyone have any ideas what it could be? We’ve changed his diet, given him grain-free treats, had a skin scrape the lot, but no one seems to be able to tell us what it is.

Any help would be great as I hate seeing him so itchy and frustrated.

[image] [image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! :) Has anything in your house / environment changed in line with the flare up (not necessarily related to the dog)? I heard once a dog exhibited itchy paws straight after the carpet had been cleaned, for example.

Comment: Thank you! No nothing has changed specifically, Barry (our Frenchie) spent time in the garden yesterday, could it be the grass?

Answer (score 2):

I see little swollen bumps, especially around the armpits. I also see the red on their chest. These areas are not typical for seasonal allergies, and combined with the bumps, I think you have something else on your hand.

[image]

From [10 Signs Your Dog Has Seasonal Allergies: East Shore Vet](http://www.eastshorevet.com/10-signs-dog-seasonal-allergies/)

If your dog has always been itchy, my guess would be a food allergy. I know that you said that you've changed his diet, but depending on what he is allergic to, those new diet changes may still have had the allergen! For example, I recently discovered that one of my dogs was allergic to poultry. So when I switched from food to food to grain free, the allergy remained because pretty much every commercial brand of dog food and treats had that ingredient.

Also, when you are giving your dog treats, this includes more ingredients into your dog's diet, making the issue of finding the allergen more complicated. It can take months before your dog's immune system calms down after a change in diet to notice the change. So if you are looking for a food allergen, it's best to keep the dog on an extremely, extremely strict diet, so you don't have to repeat the process of weeding out ingredients longer or get bad results (say, your dog had a chicken allergy and you fed it a chicken jerky strip while on a chicken-free food, so the allergy remained).

I also found [this webpage](http://www.organic-pet-digest.com/very-red-slightly-raised-dog-skin-rash-in-armpit-with-hot-spots.html) with a dog that has a skin rash that seemed to have similar spots to yours .

Answer (score -1):

[image][image][image]

My French bulldog has been like this since he was 3 months old. He is 10 months now, it comes and goes. He has been on steroids and a special cream. I have changed his diet but the vet said don’t ever give your dog grain free as it affects their heart. Now I have a food that breaks down, it’s a Hypoallergenic, but it needs to be a prescription food, not ones in the supermarket that say it! I have Purena HA.

I don’t know what he is allergic to, I think it’s grass! Also luckily my steroids for my asthma are the same steroids the vets give him, plus I have a cream called Daktacort, save the vet bills when I put the cream on don’t let them lick it! He had healed overnight! Also baking soda helps. I have researched, tried everything, I don’t why he is fine one minute and then it flares up, it could be the weather!

[image]

Comment: Hi Lisa, thank you for sharing your experience. I have edited your answer a bit to make it easier to read. If you have a new question please click the Ask Question button at the top of the page.